# Creating alternative implementation of install.packages based on checking status of cran mirrors

Tags: r

A bit of an odd request. I am looking to create an alternative or adapted install.packages that will first check which mirrors are available. Is there some easy existing method to see which mirrors are up and running without error? Or an existing package that attempts do something like this?

Alternatively, I have been thinking of making use of the below two mirrors to use `cloud.r` first and then `packgmanager` resources. I pinged both these and they don't seem to be at the same location but I am not 100% sure what would happen if the one were to fail and what effect it would have on the second one. Any advice or guidance?

```
options(repos = c(REPO_NAME = "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/latest"))

options(repos = c(REPO_NAME = "https://cloud.r-project.org/"))
```